# Program Works When Parsing Semicolon as "Semicolon:=True" doesn't work when "Tab:=True"

Tags: vba

I am trying to modify existing code that allows the user to create charts from text data. This code works when the incoming files data uses semicolons to separate the different data it works, but when I changed it to parse using tabs it does not work. The following is the error message that I get:

"Run time error '1004',The pivotTable name is not valid, to create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organize as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable Field, you must type a new name for the field."

I have tried a few things including changing the name of the PivotTable but that has not worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

I am new to VBA, with no prior experience. I have been given this code to make it work with Text(tab delimited) files.

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "'ISEDIS_Data'!R1C1:R5000C81", Version:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable 
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
        TableName:="MYTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

The expected output is an excel workbook with 5 tabs. The first four being charts, while the last being the excel data parsed in separate cells.

Comment: How are you importing the text data? If it's a problem with the delimiter (based on your description of the behavior), that's likely more relevant code than the pivot cache creation.